# Comparing CSV files in Python - Trouble with loops

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'm trying to devise a python script to read through a series of CSV files, pick out the first column and compare each line(row) against a master CSV file.  If there are any matches then it prints the match and the line number into the console.  It also posts the file name and the match that was found within another CSV file.

So far, everything is working well except this darn loop I have going on.  Once the script comes to the loop it flies past it and re-loops it for each file located in the targeted directory of CSV files.  I know it's processing the loop because it outputs the number of lines in each CSV file into the console.  However, it does not print out whether a match was found or not, so there's something going on with my nested loop.

```
for eachFile in files:

#each file being compared
target = scanDir+eachFile

#print a message to the console letting the user know the file we're processing
print
print 'Scanning begun on: ' + target

#open the master file we'll be using during this loop
f1 = file(masterFile, 'r')
csv1 = csv.reader(f1)



with open(target, 'rb') as targetFile:

    #for fun, let's output the rows we'll be processing in the target file
    numberOfRows = sum(1 for row in targetFile)
    print 'This file contains ' + str(numberOfRows) + ' rows to review.' 

    reader = csv.reader(targetFile)

    for targetRow in reader: #not processing this loop :(
        foundMatch = False
        for masterRow in csv1:
            if targetRow[0] == masterRow[0]:
                lineNumber = targetFile.line_num
                print 'MATCH FOUND! ' + targetRow[0] + 'found on row ' + lineNumber
                print
                _includes.CVSWriter.writeRow(target, targetRow[0])
                foundMatch = True
            if not foundMatch:
                print 'No matches found in ' + target
                print
f1.close()

print 'Scanning Completed'
print
```

I have six files for the loop to scan, all of differing lengths and values.  I even have one that's completely blank, and that still doesn't say "No matches found".  I'm at a total loss, and I'm sure this is something easy to fix, but at this point I could use an outside look at it.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: A good start would to be to print the values of `targetRow[0]` and `masterRow[0]` in the nested loop. That way you can debug what the actual values are and check why the comparison is always returning `False`.

Comment: Also, you are looping through every value in `csv1` while `reader`  is still on its first iteration. On `reader`'s second iteration `csv1` will probably not do what you expect as you can't iterate through a csv reader twice.

Comment: to add on to what figs said, have you tried resetting your iterator ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868354 ?

Comment: research `pandas`. it makes this kind of stuff trivial. but without seeing sample data, i can't give you an exact answer. but it will go something like: `master = pd.read_csv('master'); current = pd.read_csv('current'); current[master.first_column == current.first_column].first_column`

Comment: I read up on the other article Matt Ball posted and I think I got it so it's iterating like it should, however the results are the same.  Using:' f1.seek(0)' after 'for masterRow in csv1'  I "think" that's where I need to reset it?

Comment: I'd like to help but it's difficult if you don't show (samples of) your data files and don't show the real output of your program. Please do you a favour and edit your question to show the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the row count from your code, you're *exhausting* the input file and the `reader` loop, that you say doesn't execute, is executing but stops immediately because your `reader` has nothing to read.

#### Addendum

I suggest that you slurp in at once your reference file and save just the first line item in a `set` data structure (in this example I have to use different data from yours, as you didn't care to ask a complete question)

```
from  csv import reader
ref = 'cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv'
ref_set = {el[0] for el in reader(open(ref))
```

the last line being a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Now you're ready to iterate over target files (in my example, just one file...)

```
for tgf in ('cc2012xyz2_5_6dp.csv',):
    rtg = reader(open(tgf))
    matches = 0
    for tg_row in rtg: 
        if tg_row[0] in s1:
            print '# MATCH FOUND! ', tg_row[0], 'found on row', rtg.line_num
            matches += 1
    if matches == 1:
        print '# In file',f2,'there is 1 (one) match.'
    elif matches:
        print  '# In file',f2,'there are',matches,'matches.'
    else:
        print  '# In file',f2,'there are no matches.'
```

When I run the code above on my data files I obtain the following output

```
# MATCH FOUND!  395.0 found on row 2
# MATCH FOUND!  420.0 found on row 7
# MATCH FOUND!  445.0 found on row 12
# MATCH FOUND!  460.0 found on row 15
# MATCH FOUND!  475.0 found on row 18
# MATCH FOUND!  510.0 found on row 25
# In file cc2012xyz2_5_6dp.csv there are 6 matches.
```

I cannot help with respect to your line

```
        _includes.CVSWriter.writeRow(target, targetRow[0])
```

because I don't know what this stuff is all about (I **did** a google search but the only hits were from your question...)

Further, if you still have `IndexError` I **guess** (as in, you didn't ask a proper question) that it means that some of your data is not in a format that a csv reader can parse properly.

I cannot be of further help unless you seriously edit your question. Goodbye.

Comment: I removed the counter and printed out the targetRow and masterRow variables.  Both are printing correctly, however, when I try to run it again with targetRow[0] and masterRow[0] it's giving me an error saying  the list index is out of range.  That's where I'm lost at...