# Python: Reading in .csv data as dictionary and printing out data as dictionary to .csv file?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, input, output

I'm writing a python executable script that does the following:

I want to gather information from a .csv file and read it into python as a dictionary. This .csv file contains several columns of information with headings, and I only want to extract particular columns (those columns with specific headings I want) , and print those columns out to another .csv file. I am using the functions `DictReader` and `DictWriter`.

I am reading in the .csv file as a dictionary (with the headings being the key and the column values being the items),and output the information as a dictionary to another .csv file.

After I read it in, I print out the items in the particular headings (so I can double check what I have read it). I then open up a new .csv file and want to write the data (which I have just read in) as a dictionary. I can write in the keys (column headings) but my code doesn't print any of the item values for some reason. The headings that I want in this case are 'Name' and 'DOB'.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import os.path
import re
import sys
import pdb
import csv

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1],'rU'),delimiter = ',')
for line in csv_file:
    print line['Name'] + ',' + line['DOB']

fieldnames = ['Name','DOB']
test_file = open('test2.csv','wr')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(test_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)

csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))

for row in csv_file:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
test_file.close()
```

Any ideas of where I'm going wrong ? I want to print the item values under their their corresponding column headers in the output file.

I am using python 2.7.11 on a Mac machine. I am also printing values to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unfortunately tricked by your own testing, that is, the printing of the individual rows. By looping through `csv_file` initially, you've exhausted the iterator and are at the end. Further iterations, as done in the bottom of your code, are not possible and will be ignored.

Your question is essentially a duplicate of various other question, such as [how to read from a CSV file repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868354/reading-from-csvs-in-python-repeatedly). Albeit that the issue here comes up in a different way: you didn't realise what the problem was, while those questions do know the cause, but not the solution.

Answers to those questions tell you to simply reset the file pointer of the input file. Unfortunately, the input file gets closed promptly after reading, in your current code.

Thus, something like this should work:

```
infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rU')
csv_file = csv.DictReader(infile ,delimiter = ',')

<all other code>

infile.seek(0)
for row in csv_file:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
test_file.close()
infile.close()
```

---

As an aside, just use the `with` statement when opening files:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as infile, open('test2.csv', 'wr') as outfile:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(infile ,delimiter = ',')
    for line in csv_file:
        print line['Name'] + ',' + line['DOB']
    fieldnames = ['Name','DOB']
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    infile.seek(0)
    for row in csv_file:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Note: `DictWriter` will take care of the header row. No need to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks - your works well: I just had to add a field to the DictWriter method: csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=field_names,extrasaction='ignore'), otherwise I was getting an error: "ValueError: dict contains fields not in field names" .